# Grub Bypassed (Dual Boot, Dual Disk System)

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

1. My system has 2 disks. (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb)
2. I am dual-booting Linux Mint 13 and Windows 7.

   Windows 7 is on /dev/sda1
   Linux Mint's / is on /dev/sda6
   Linux Mint's /boot is on /dev/sda5
3. I just installed Linux Mint 17.
4. During installation, I formatted all the Linux Mint 13 partitions, but assigned the same mount points.
5. The Windows 7 partition was left intact.
6. Bootloader was installed on /dev/sda
7. After installation, when I tried to boot up, I got the error:

   ```
   error: no such device: XXXXX
   Entering rescue mode...
   grub rescue>
   ```
8. I read around and though that perhaps I installed the bootloader on the wrong disk.
9. So I repeated the whole Linux Mint 17 installation process, but this time, selected /dev/sdb as the bootloader installation device.
10. Now, when I boot up, it bypasses grub altogether and boots into Linux Mint 17 directly.

How can I get the system to boot into grub?

ADDED:
BTW, not sure if this is crucial, but I just found that the Windows 7 (Loader) is on /dev/sdb1. This was created automatically when I installed Windows 7 (previously, I installed Windows 7 followed by Linux Mint 13).

Answer (score 1):

After procrastinating for a while (didn't really need to boot to the other OS, so bypassing GRUB was OK...), I decided to try again. As in, re-installing again.

And this time, it worked, and I can't explain why.

The only thing I did differently (and I can't explain why I did that... just blindly trying stuff I guess), was that when booting from the USB drive (that contained Linux Mint ISO), instead of selecting "UEFI: Flash Drive AU_USB20 8.07", I selected "Flash Drive AU_USB20 8.07" (yup, without the "UEFI") instead.

So now it works. GRUB shows, the installer detected Windows 7 as well, and booting to both OSes are fine.

Posting here so that anyone facing the same problem might want to give it a shot. But I have no idea if this is the correct solution and why it happens. So if anyone can explain it would be best!